# How to calculate the standard errors of ERGM predicted probabilities?

Tags: standard-error, statnet

I'm having trouble estimating the standard errors from the predicted probabilities from a ERGM model, to calculate a confidence interval. Getting the predicted probabilities is not a problem, but I want to get a sense of the uncertainty surrounding the predictions.

Below is a reproduceable example based on the data set of marriage and business ties among Renaissance Florentine families.

```
library(statnet)
data(flo)
flomarriage <- network(flo,directed=FALSE)
flomarriage

flomarriage %v% "wealth" <- c(10,36,27,146,55,44,20,8,42,103,48,49,10,48,32,3)
flomarriage
gest <- ergm(flomarriage ~ edges + 
               absdiff("wealth"))
summary(gest)

plogis(coef(gest)[['edges']] + coef(gest)[['absdiff.wealth']]*10)
```

Based on the model, it is estimated that a wealth difference of 10 corresponds to a 0.182511 probability of a tie. My first question is, is this a correct interpretation? And my second question is, how does one calculate the standard error of this probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct interpretation for a dyad-independent model such as this one. For a dyad-dependent model, it would be the conditional probability given the rest of the network.

You can obtain the standard error of the prediction on the *logit* scale by rewriting your last line as a dot product of a weight vector and the coefficient vector:

```r
eta <- sum(c(1,10)*coef(gest))
plogis(eta)
```

then, since `vcov(gest)` is the covariance matrix of parameter estimates, and using the variance formulas (e.g., [http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat401/lecture-13.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=stat401/lecture-13.pdf)),

```r
(var.eta <- c(1,10)%*%vcov(gest)%*%c(1,10))
```

You can then get the variance (and the standard error) of the predicted probability using the Delta Method (e.g., https://blog.methodsconsultants.com/posts/delta-method-standard-errors/). However, unless you require the standard error as such, as opposed to a confidence interval, my advice would be to first calculate the interval for eta (i.e., `eta + qnorm(c(0.025,0.975))*sqrt(var.eta)`), then call `plogis()` on the endpoints.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic, precisely what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopheLesschaeve , in that case, can I trouble you to mark the answer as accepted? (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers .)

Answer (score 1):

Really very helpful answer! Many thanks for it.
Here's just a small, almost cosmetic note about the suggested formula: 1) the upper bound in qnorm should be 0.975, not 0.0975, and 2) use matrix multiplication before sqrt --> `eta + qnorm(c(0.025,0.975))%*%sqrt(var.eta)`.